# Python -- Program that takes user input and processes it through an equation and returns a time which is 16 hours later

Tags: python

So I designed a code in Jupyter Notebook that takes the time you last ate and translates it over to 16 hours later. This initial block of code doesn't exactly work, because 0000 doesn't work and any input that starts with a 0 would push to my else statement (1600).
I really want this thing to:

- Ask for what time you ate last in hh:mm am/pm
- Convert it into 24h time, input it into the function
- Have it do it's calculation
- Spit out hh:mm of the calculation which is 16 hours later.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
def fasting_time(time_last_ate):
    if time_last_ate > 1 and time_last_ate < 1200:
        result1 = add(time_last_ate,1600) - 1200
        return result1
    if time_last_ate > 1200 and time_last_ate < 2359:
        result2 = add(time_last_ate, 1600)- 1200
        return result2
    else: 
        return('1600')
```

Then, I tried using a time converter to translate the integer over to something usable. However, this code will only take strings:

```
from datetime import datetime
import parsedatetime as pdt # $ pip install parsedatetime

cal = pdt.Calendar()
for time_str in ['1600']:
    dt, flags = cal.parseDT(time_str)
    assert flags
    print(dt)
```

output looks like:

```
2018-04-06 16:00:00
```

BUT I can't put `fasting_time(n)` and insert it in `for time_str in ['1600']:

Soooo. how do I make it work?

Comment: Why do you have a for loop at all? There's no point in looping if you only have one value. And why can't you put the function call there?

Answer (score 0):

I would look in to  `datetime.timedelta`

> class datetime.timedelta
>   A duration expressing the difference between two date, time, or datetime instances to microsecond resolution.

Your code could be rewritten to do a `strptime(input)` (string parse time) with a timedelta of the desired amount returned in the `strftime(result)`(string from time).